# How can I make sure that data from a certain Collection arrives before other data?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have two collections, `tableA` and `tableB`. Documents in `tableB` have a field that corresponds to the `_id` in one document in `tableA` (basically, a foreign key). For example:

```
tableB.find({tableA_id: xxx}) // returns documents whose tableA_id is xxx
```

Now, I have an `observeChanges` listening to the `tableA` collection. If `tableA` has new or updated documents, I need to get documents from `tableB` with the new `_ids`:

```
tableA.find({}).observeChanges({
    changed: function(new, old) {
        tableB.find({tableA_id: new._id});
    }
    ...
});
```

However, sometimes, the update from `tableA` reaches the client first, even if I insert documents in `tableB` first.

```
// This is how I insert data in the server.
tableB.insert(...);
tableA.insert(...);
```

The updates from `tableB` arrive shortly after.

My current solution is basically to do a `Meteor.call` inside `observeChanges`, which gets the new data from the server manually, though it's inelegant. I also thought of calling a `Meteor.setTimeout` before getting the documents from `tableB`.

Is there any way that I can ensure that data from `tableA` will arrive first?

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but have you tried using [publish-with-relations](https://github.com/erundook/meteor-publish-with-relations) instead of writing your own join?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to clarify your schema design and why you are using two tables? There may be a simpler way to structure your schema, or to have one collection instead of two.

But lets assume that two separate collections are necessary: Have you tried creating a callback function?

e.g. create the callback function along these lines:

```
myFunctionName = function(arg1, arg2,...,callback){
  //run your first query here...
  //then run your callback function
  if (callback && typeof(callback) === "function") {  
    callback();
  }
});
```

Then you would call your function along these lines:

```
myFunctionName(arg1, arg2, ..., function(){
  // run your second query here...
  // note: this is your "callback" function
}
```

The code will run myFunctionName first - i.e. query 1 - then will run the callback function - i.e. query 2. You can pass variables from the parent function into the callback function, if you wish.